# Traversing through dictionary keys

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to get a location of a key in a dictionary?

for example, if my keys are  23, 44, 56, 66 and I want the get they key at location 0 it would return me 23.  Or key at location 2 would return 56.

Are dictionary keys traversable like this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? So you want to search a dictionary and find out where a value is inside the dictionary?

Comment: I'm trying to pick a random key from a dictionary.  Just the key not the value

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: it is a dictionary like this `Dictionary <int, List <int>>` i would like to pick a random int from all of the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx):

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as
>   a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its
>   key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

So the indices will not be consistent, if ever you did get it.

I suggest you use a `List<T>` using something like a `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` or a Class, if you can.

Answer (score 2):

So yes Dictionary's are able to be iterated through because they are a type of ICollection.

If you really wanted to just find a random key you could just create a random number and use

```
 var randomNumber = 5; (or however you want to get a random number)
 var randomKey = yourDictionary.ElementAt(randomNumber).Key;
```

So this will get the key in the sixth position of the dictionary, and if you wanted you could also get the value by just saying .Value;

Comment: hmmm, i've tried ElementAt but it doesn't seem to work in Unity3d for some reason.  It might be an extension method not available for me in Unity.  But yeah this is exactly what i'm looking for except it is not working.

Comment: Other then placing all keys in an array and picking an index of that array, I'm not sure if there can be an easier way (in Unity).

Comment: Note that a Dictionary is an unordered collection, so there isn't a sixth position in any Dictionary! ICollection does not specify order.